# AssertThat returns error for matching List

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to do a `Junit` unit test in `Spring Boot` with `Mockito`.

But I am getting the following error.
I am not able to figure out what is going wrong from the error
Codesnippet:
https://pastebin.com/RDUXk5QF

```
public List<JobPartRecentActivity> jobPartRecentActivityList() {

        Date timestamp = new Date();
        JobPartRecentActivity jobData = new JobPartRecentActivity();
        jobData.setCommments("TestComments");
        jobData.setEventId(1234L);
        jobData.setJobNumber(1234L);
        jobData.setTagNumber(1L);
        jobData.setSerialNumber("6789");
        jobData.setPartNumber("12345");
        jobData.setOperationName("Receiving");
        jobData.setOperationSequence(1L);
        jobData.setOperationCode("02");
        jobData.setPartStatus("COMPLETE");
        jobData.setTimestamp(timestamp);
        jobData.setSystemActionTaken("Done");

        List<JobPartRecentActivity> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            dataList.add(jobData);
        }

        return dataList;

    }

    @Test
    public void testremoveDuplicateEntries() throws Exception {
        //setup
        List<JobPartRecentActivity> actualdataList = new ArrayList<>();
        Date timestamp = new Date();
        JobPartRecentActivity jobDataActual = new JobPartRecentActivity();
        jobDataActual.setCommments("TestComments");
        jobDataActual.setEventId(1234L);
        jobDataActual.setJobNumber(1234L);
        jobDataActual.setTagNumber(1L);
        jobDataActual.setSerialNumber("6789");
        jobDataActual.setPartNumber("12345");
        jobDataActual.setOperationName("Receiving");
        jobDataActual.setOperationSequence(1L);
        jobDataActual.setOperationCode("02");
        jobDataActual.setPartStatus("COMPLETE");
        jobDataActual.setTimestamp(timestamp);
        jobDataActual.setSystemActionTaken("Done");
        actualdataList.add(jobDataActual);
        //execute
        List<JobPartRecentActivity> expecteddataList = new ArrayList<>();
        expecteddataList = eventEngine.removeDuplicateEntries(jobPartRecentActivityList());
        //verify
        assertThat(actualdataList, is(expecteddataList));

    }
}
```

--

> Error:
>       java.lang.AssertionError: 
>       Expected: is <[JobPartRecentActivity [rnum=null, eventId=1234, jobNumber=1234, tagNumber=1, serialNumber=6789, partNumber=12345,
>   operationSequence=1, operationName=Receiving, operationCode=02,
>   partStatus=COMPLETE, comments=TestComments, changeMadeBy=null,
>   timestamp=Thu Nov 09 16:11:42 CST 2017, systemActionTaken=Done]]>
>            but: was <[JobPartRecentActivity [rnum=null, eventId=1234, jobNumber=1234, tagNumber=1, serialNumber=6789, partNumber=12345,
>   operationSequence=1, operationName=Receiving, operationCode=02,
>   partStatus=COMPLETE, comments=TestComments, changeMadeBy=null,
>   timestamp=Thu Nov 09 16:11:42 CST 2017, systemActionTaken=Done]]>
>         at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
>         at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
>         at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
>         at com.ge.power.brs.engines.impl.EventEngineTests.testremoveDuplicateEntries(EventEngineTests.java:172)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>         at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
>         at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code, don't use external links. Also, add the source code of `JobPartRecentActivity` as well.

Comment: Sure..Let me see, if it allows

Comment: You're telling us it's a matching list, but clearly JUnit disagrees. Without any evidence either way, I'm going to side with JUnit.

Comment: Sure..JUnit is correct, but need to know whats wrong

Comment: We can't help without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You heed to add `equals` and `hashcode` to `JobPartRecentActivity`, because assertThat(..., is(...)); compare by reference if object doesn't have `equals` and `hashcode`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Date. It is comparing timestamp. When the expecteddatalist object is created and the actualdatalist object is created, there is indeed a time difference.Once we remove the Date code, the assertThat is working fine